# In batch file loop, applying JSLint to files, excluding some extensions

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that verifies all the javascripts except the ones with .min.js in their extension. I am seeing that my_file only gets value of one file. It is always the same, whereas when I echo %%~nxf, it always changes.

```
@echo off

for /r %cd% %%f in (*.js) do (
    set my_file=%%~nxf
    set fileNoMin=%file:.min=%
    if %file% == %fileNoMin% (
            echo ********** Verifying %%~nxf **********
        cscript /nologo JsLint\jslint-for-wsh.js %%f
    )
)
```

Please help me with this :)- What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

inside a code block you need `dalayed expansion`  and `!variables!`:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

for /r "%cd%" %%f in (*.js) do (
     set "my_file=%%~nxf"
     set "fileNoMin=!my_file:.min=!"
     if "!my_file!"=="!fileNoMin!" (
                echo ********** Verifying %%~nxf **********
          cscript /nologo JsLint\jslint-for-wsh.js %%f
     )
)
```